# Where does QtQuick attach the buffers to the FBO?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

When using QQuickFramebufferObject, the QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer is asked to create a FBO and also to output in this FBO (the content of the FBO being merged with the overall GUI by QtQuick behind the hood).

Now the Renderer is only asked to create the FBO (QOpenGLFramebufferObject), not the buffers themselves (Textures or RenderBuffers).

Where are these buffers attached to the FBO?

Comment: `QOpenGLFramebufferObject` has a property called `attachment` which should be set when `Renderer` calls `createFramebufferObject`. I think Qt backend will create corresponding attachments and buffers according to the settings.

Comment: You mean if it isn't done in createFramebufferObject() the Qt backend has a default attachment policy?